# Limit of a sequence of integrals involving a continuous function $f(t)$ and sequence of exponential functions equals $f(0)$

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, I want to prove that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}{ne^{-nt}f(t)dt}=f(0)
$$
If we knew that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and that $f' \in L[0,1]$ then we could write
$$
\begin{split}
 \int_{0}^{1}{ne^{-nt}f(t)dt} & =  -e^{-nt}f(t) \Big|_0^1 + \int_{0}^{1}e^{-nt}f(t)dt \\
                              & =-e^{-n}f(1)+f(0)+\int_{0}^{1}e^{-nt}f'(t)dt
\end{split}
$$
And since $|e^{-nt}f(t)| \leq |f'(t)| \in L_{1}([0,1])$ for each $n \geq 1$ and $e^{-nt}f(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ a.e it would follow by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem that this last integral converges to $0$ and thus it follows that the total limit is indeed $f(0)$. As you can see the problem with this idea is that we don't know that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and that $f' \in L[0,1]$ so I am missing something.

Any help?

In advance thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$
\int_{0}^{1}{ne^{-nt}f(t)dt}=\int_0^{n} e^{-s}f(\frac s  n) ds
$$ and $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-s}ds=1$. [You can use Dominated Convergence Theorem].

Comment: I see, thank you very much! :)